# Member function with multi-level list in Common Lisp

Tags: list, function, common-lisp, member

I'm trying to understand how it works member function with list and list of lists.
Here an example.

```
(member '(A 6) '((A 7) (B 6) (E 6) (D 5)) :test #'string-equal :key #'second)
```

I want to check with the member function if the second argument of the list '(A 6) is member of the second list in input.
The answer should be

```
true
```

but I'm doing something wrong, because Common Lisp reply:

```
 Error: Cannot coerce (A 6) to type STRING.
```

So how can I take the second argument from the first list?
Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are missing is that the `:key` argument is *not* applied to the first argument of [`member`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mem_m.htm).

Another thing is that `second` will return the *number*, not the *symbol*.

Thus:

```
(member 'A '((A 7) (B 6) (E 6) (D 5)) :test #'string-equal :key #'first)
==> ((A 7) (B 6) (E 6) (D 5))
(member 'C '((A 7) (B 6) (E 6) (D 5)) :test #'string-equal :key #'first)
==> NIL
(member 'E '((A 7) (B 6) (E 6) (D 5)) :test #'string-equal :key #'first)
==> ((E 6) (D 5))
```

Note that the return value is the *tail*, not the matched list element.
This is to allow the use of `member` as a predicate, i.e., to distinguish between finding `nil` and finding nothing:

```
(member nil '(1 2 nil 3))
==> (NIL 3)
(find nil '(1 2 nil 3))
==> NIL
(find t '(1 2 nil 3))
==> NIL
```